# fallo en conexión de java al LDAP con spring para una federación deidentidad

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

estoy realizando practicas academicas en una empresa, fui encargado de realizar una federación de identidad que tiene conexiones con multiples LDAP, estoy realizando pruevas con uno LDAP, agregue dependencias al pom de spring security, manejo mla interfaz grafica de inicio con xhtml, un LAMP de ubuntu server 18.04 LTE, PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1,  MySQL Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu) y un apache2, estoy trabajando con eclipse y el ultimo java disponible, al intentar ejecutar en el servidor tomcat 9 obtengo el siguiente error

```
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FEDERACION]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start  component  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FEDERACION]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/FEDERACION] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2139)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2083)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2029)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1999)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1952)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1156)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more

nov 19, 2018 8:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FEDERACION]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FEDERACION]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan  for annotations for web application [/FEDERACION] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2139)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2083)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2029)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1999)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1952)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1156)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more

nov 19, 2018 8:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FEDERACION]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FEDERACION]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/FEDERACION] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2139)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2083)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2029)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1999)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1952)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1156)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more
```

mi clase  (que no se si este bien) de seguridad es

```
package control;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import  org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.LdapShaPasswordEncoder;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception   {
 auth
 .ldapAuthentication()
 .userDnPatterns(“uid={0},ou=people”)
 .groupSearchBase(“ou=person”)
 .contextSource()
 .url(“ldaps://***.***.***.***:636/cn=Monitor,dc=edu,dc=co”)
 .and()
 .passwordCompare()
 .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
 .passwordAttribute(“********”);
  }
 }
```

mi pom es

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>FEDERACION</groupId>
<artifactId>FEDERACION</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.6.2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>
</project>
```

y mi web.xml es

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
<display-name>FEDERACION</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <display-name>seguridadSpring</display-name>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

no se que tengo mal o si estoy mesclando tutorias, si conocern una parami problema seria muy bueno, hay que tener en cuenta que debo realizar un CAS

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** No tengo una respuesta, esto es lo que he encontrado por si te es de utilidad.

La excepción es bastante inusual. Buscando por Google ["java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application due to a StackOverflowError"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.IllegalStateException%3A+Unable+to+complete+the+scan+for+annotations+for+web+application+due+to+a+StackOverflowError) nos sale un enlace a [esta pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584495/unable-to-complete-the-scan-for-annotations-for-web-application-app-due-to-a) que tiene problemas con exactamente la misma clase.

La base del problema en la pregunta relacionada es que hay dos versiones de la librería bouncycastle que causan incompatibilidades. Sin embargo, con tu `pom.xml` hago `mvn dependency:tree` y obtengo

> [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ FEDERACION ---
>   [INFO] FEDERACION:FEDERACION:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
>   [INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
>   [INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:provided
>   [INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.2.9:compile
>   [INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.2.9:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.6.2.1:compile
>   [INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.11:compile
>   [INFO] |  - com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.6.0:runtime
>   [INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:8.0:provided
>   [INFO] |  - com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.0:provided
>   [INFO] |     - javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.7:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.7:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  |  - aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
>   [INFO] |  |     - org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
>   [INFO] |  |     - org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.3.2.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-all:jar:1.5.5:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.apache.directory.shared:shared-ldap:jar:0.9.15:compile
>   [INFO] |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
>   [INFO] |     +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
>   [INFO] |     +- org.apache.directory.shared:shared-asn1:jar:0.9.15:compile
>   [INFO] |     +- org.apache.directory.shared:shared-ldap-constants:jar:0.9.15:compile
>   [INFO] |     - antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
>   [INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
>   [INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
>   [INFO] - org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE:test
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 56.662 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-20T10:16:38+01:00
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/150M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Solo hay una aparición de bouncycastle, y Tomcat 9 no trae por defecto bouncycastle. Así que yo miraría de:

- Asegurarme que no hayas metido bouncycastle en tu instalación de Tomcat
- Si eso falla, revisar las compatibilidades de cada componente. Si acaso, pasarlos a la última versión estable (que ya debería soportar Tomcat 9).
- Cambiar la librería bouncycastle por una más moderna (hacer `<exclude>` de la librería en `spring-security-jwt` y añadirla como una dependencia por separado).